# About the program "Hello world" from CUDA C on linux

Tags: linux, cuda

Please I need a help.
I'm new user of linux. I installed the CUDA C Driver. I have tested the bandwidth sample and it works well. when I compiled this program:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
__global__ void helloFromGPU (void)
{
printf("Hello World from GPU!\n");
}
int main(void)
{
// hello from cpu
printf("Hello World from CPU!\n");
helloFromGPU <<<1, 10>>>();
cudaDeviceReset();
return 0;
}
```

and tried to execute its binary I got

```
$ ./code_1
Hello World from CPU!
```

and the device code doesn't show expected result of repeating the string 10 times.
I got this result dear Robert:

```
  yasin@yasin-Inspiron-5558:~/Documents/Programming$ cuda-memcheck ./code_1
    ========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
    Hello World from CPU!
    ========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
    yasin@yasin-Inspiron-5558:~/Documents/Programming$
```

I have done what you asked @Robert:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_17_18:36:13_PDT_2013
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.5, V5.5.0
yasin@yasin-Inspiron-5558:~$ nvidia-smi
Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error
yasin@yasin-Inspiron-5558:~$
```

Comment: 1. add a `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` before the `cudaDeviceReset();`   2. run your code with `cuda-memcheck` and report the results.

Comment: The result is not expected. What's the problem?

Comment: What is the actual output when you run your code with `cuda-memcheck` ?  Please copy the output and paste it into your question.  You can edit your question, just click on the edit link above below the `linux`  `cuda` tags.  Like this:  `cuda-memcheck ./code_1`

Comment: Dear Ropert, first thank you for help. Second I got this result:
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= code_1.cu: Permission denied
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors

Comment: Thats not correct. You don't want to run `cuda-memcheck ./code_1.cu` you want to run `cuda-memcheck ./code_1`

Comment: @RobertCrovella Please look again at the question end you will find the results

Comment: what is the output of `nvcc --version` and `nvidia-smi` ?  What exact command line did you use to compile this code?  Please edit the output into your question.

Comment: perhaps you've discovered the underlying problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988385/executing-device-query-cuda-sample-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I havn't discovered it. please look at the results you required at the end of the post.

Comment: The fact that `nvidia-smi` is reporting an error means that CUDA was not installed correctly on that machine.  Your statement in the question that you ran `bandwidthTest` and it ran correctly cannot be correct if `nvidia-smi` is reporting that error.

Comment: Yeah,  @RobertCrovella the CUDA Driver wasn't installed properly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply the problem was that the CUDA wasn't installed properly.