# Executing device Query Cuda Sample on Ubuntu

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-14.04

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd060.png)   I got this problem on Ubuntu when I tried to execute the executable deviceQuery:

```
CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)    
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35
-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Result = FAIL
```

I updated the driver  and then I tried to run bandwidth test. I got the message:

```
FATAL:Module nvidia not found. 
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
no Cuda-capable device is detected
```

.
Although when running the command:

```
$ lspci | grep -I nvidia
```

I got:

```
NVIDIA Corporation GK208M[GeForce 920m] (rev a1)
```

@Pavan Yalamanchili

Comment: I updated the driver  and then I tried to run bandwidth test. I got the message: 
FATAL:Module nvidia not found. 
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 38
no Cuda-capable device is detected.

Comment: @ Pavan Yalamanchili
Please I need your help. I have updated the cuda driver as indicated in the post and still the problem exists. please read the rest of my post and you will understand.

Comment: @ Pavan Yalamanchili
Please, I'm waiting your reply:
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2013 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jul_17_18:36:13_PDT_2013
Cuda compilation tools, release 5.5, V5.5.0
yasin@yasin-Inspiron-5558:~$ nvidia-smi
Failed to initialize NVML: Unknown Error
yasin@yasin-Inspiron-5558:~$